# SetCookie for multiple form elements

Tags: javascript, cookies

Right now my test form sets the `location` to a Cookie but I have four additional fields that I would like to set to cookies. Within the form `OnSubmit` how is that handled?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
      var today = new Date();
      var expire = new Date();

      if (!nDays)
        nDays = 1;

      expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="javascript:return setCookie('location', this.querySelector('select').value, 365);">
    <input name="first" type="text" required />
    <input name="last" type="text" required />
    <input name="social" type="text" required />
    <input name="email" type="email" required />
    <select name="location">
      <option value="location1">Location 1</option>
      <option value="location2">Location 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setCookie()` multiple times, separated by `;`.

Get rid of the `return` statement, it's not needed since `setCookie()` doesn't return anything. And there's no need for `javascript:` before it; that's only needed when you put JS where a URL is expected, like `action` or `href`.

```
  <form onsubmit="setCookie('location', this.querySelector('select').value, 365);setCookie('first', this.querySelector('[name=first]').value, 365);setCookie('last', this.querySelector('[name=last]').value, 365);setCookie('social', this.querySelector('[name=social]').value, 365);setCookie('email', this.querySelector('[name=email]').value, 365);">
```

Comment: any recommended error handlers that should be put in place to make sure a cookie is always set and not null? I do have a basic HTML input `required`, is that enough?

Comment: `setCookie()` could check if the value is empty and not assign the cookie.